# Python fuzzy matching

Tags: python

I have a database with a million rows that I want to match a text field to an Excel spreadsheet, however there are very few exact matches. So I've created a word list with a rank based on how popular that word is, ie the more unique the higher the score and the more likely it will match. This works well and as expected. However, it is slow as I'm looping the spreadsheet through the SQL cursor and then through a list of words.

Any suggestions on how to improve the code or even a different approach that gives a similar answer?

```
wb = xl.load_workbook(in_file, data_only=True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
max_row = sh.max_row + 1
max_col = sh.max_column + 1
with open(out_file, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for xl_row in range(2, max_row):
        matched = []
        var = sh.cell(row=xl_row, column=1).value
        count = 0
        cursor.execute(sql)
        for sql_row in cursor:
            count += 1
            r = 0
            for word in word_list:
                if word[0] in var.upper() and word[0] in sql_row[1].upper():
                    r += word[1]
            if r > 0:
                matched.append([var, sql_row[0], sql_row[1], r])
                sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(count))
                sys.stdout.flush()

        matched.sort(key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
        max_rtn = 0
        for match in matched:
            max_rtn += 1
            if max_rtn <= 5:
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
```

Example Data:

word_list =[['Inc.', 3], ['Incorporated', 3], [Inc, 3], ['Group', 50], ['Orange', 215], ['Apple', 344]

data_set_1 = ['Apple Inc.', 'Orange Group']

data_set_2 = ['The Apple Group', 'Apple Inc', 'Orange Inc.', 'Orange']

In the above example the 'The Apple Group' matches the same number of words and will probably get a similar Levenshtein (fuzzywuzzy) result to both elements in data set 1. But as Apple has a higher significance it will match to 'Apple Inc.' and not 'Orange Group'. Data set 1 is official names, data set 2 is more human data entered.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. If the code is working as expected and all you want to do is improve performance, you might get faster and better responses by posting your issue on [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Just a suggestion. As far as I understand the problem, this might be a candidate for parallelization: Have you considered using the `multiprocessing` package, dividing your list of rows into sublists of rows and threading the work on them? Just another suggestion.

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to provide a small data set/example for us to better understand the task, and also for testing? Simply edit your post to add these details :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I always forget about applying multi threading. I will give that a go.